# Updating cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a `UITableView` that allows me to have child rows when selecting the parent row so it expands.

This is my parent row:

[image]

And If I select the row then it expands:

[image]

I want to make the child row elements to indent a little bit so It really looks the below item is child.

In my `UITableViewCell` I added this code when setting the icon and title to the cell:

```
func setData(data: ExpandableCell,indexPath : NSIndexPath)
    {

        self.itemImg.image = UIImage(named: data.icon)
        self.itemTitle.text = data.title

        if(!data.isParent){

            // indent views
            self.itemImg.frame.origin.x = 53
            self.itemTitle.frame.origin.x = 85
        }

        if(data.childs.count == 0){

            // remove the expand - collpase icon when its child row
            self.expandImg.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
```

The problem that I have is that the first time the child row is shown it doesn't indent the icon and label. It works until the second time:

> First time the child row is shown (**didn't work**):

[image]

> Second time the child row is shown (**this time works!**)

[image]

Do I have to set something so it works always? I already did: `SetNeedDisplay()` but sill have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your logic is incomplete:

```
    if(!data.isParent){
```

Fine, but what if `data.isParent` is true? You don't say what to do then. Remember, cells are reused. You need to be prepared to *empty* the already populated cell and reconfigure it.

Comment: I just fix that but I still have the same behavior. Any clue @matt?

Comment: I had to find other solution, what I did is to add in the cell other two elements, one image for indent child and one label for indent child also and then hide the indent when its parent row and show when its child. Now it seems to work... really is a very strange issue. It doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: I did this: if(!data.isParent){
            
            // child indent views
            self.itemImg.frame.origin.x = 53
            self.itemTitle.frame.origin.x = 85
            
        }else{
            
            // normal indent views
            self.itemImg.frame.origin.x = 20
            self.itemTitle.frame.origin.x = 53
            
        }

Comment: It sounds great. But I don't know enough of your code to know whether you are doing that on every pass thru `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... And I don't know how you're implementing "it expands"...

Comment: Also how do I know that `data.isParent` has the right value? How do _you_ know it does? Basically what I don't understand is this. You have the world's greatest debugger. Why don't you debug? You can _see_ exactly whether and how these values are being set, and why.